# vim 8.0 file explorer only allows specific locations

Tags: windows, vim

I'm running *vim 8.0* on a windows 7 system and i'm having this issue whenever i open gvim (the one that runs in a window as opposed to running in cmd) the default path in `:pwd` is `c:\users\"user"`.
If i use the `:Explore` command it brings up the file explorer showing all the files in there but i can only go up in file paths up to `c:\users` and that's it, I can't go any upper than that.

Moreover, if i use the `:cd` command to go to a different drive (`d:\`), it does change the directory successfully and it does show it if i use :pwd but if i use :Explore it doesn't show anything, instead it just does a split screen of the same file containing the same text i have in the initial file.

More than that, if i create an `asdasd.txt` file in d:\ and open it with vim and then use `:Explore` again it does nothing, just goes back to the same line of text i was on in command mode, almost as if the program is looking for access to that directory or cancelling the command because of something like that.

Also, i used *vim 7.4* before this and it would any of the commands mentioned as expected.

Any ideas what the problem might be? does it need any special configuration?

Comment: Crosspost: http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/10753/vim-8-0-file-explorer-only-allows-specific-locations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue on netrw v.156. (netrw is vim's file explorer) There is a fix for this on the newest version which you can find [here](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW).

Answer (score 0):

If you are too lazy to update netrw at the moment, speaking of which I am not sure if that fix the issue; or if you are temporary stuck with Windows, the workaround solution is to put a shortcut in c:/Users/ of directories you want to work with. 
Of course it's not a good solution if you have a lot of directory to work with.

My observation is that it doesn't go to c: but any child dir under it.